# Retrieving table column names in SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sqlcommand

I have tried all the solutions that have been provided including using PRAGMA but i can't seem to get it to work!!! I have a program that allows the user to create a table name it and manually enter column names that they wish. I need to some how obtain the column names from the selected table. I need by "Private void loadDB" function to do this. As you can see i have used a bunch of ways of trying to get it to work however it wont extract the names.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


public class ViewTable extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String PREFERRED_LOOK_AND_FEEL = null;
    private final String tableName;
    private String[] columnNames;
    private String[][] data;
    private JTable tablePane;

    public ViewTable(String tableName){
        this.tableName=tableName;

        initComponents();
        loadDB();
        displayTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(CreateTemplate.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700,700);
        setTitle("View Table");
        setVisible(true);


    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        mainPanel.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(this.tableName);
        titleLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
        titleLabel.setForeground(Color.orange);
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(titleLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Finish");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                close_window();
            }
        });
        exitButton.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(20,20,20,20)));
        topPanel.add(exitButton,BorderLayout.EAST);

    }

    private void close_window(){ this.dispose(); }

    private void loadDB(){
        //String com = "SELECT sql from sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = '"+tableName+"' AND type = 'table'";
        //String com = "PRAGMA table_info( "+tableName+" );";
        //String com = "INSERT null";
        //SQLCommands.SQLCommand(com);
        //String com = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master";
        //String[] output = SQLCommands.returnSQLCommand(com);
        //String com = "SELECT * FROM (PRAGMA table_info("+tableName+");"; 
        //String[] output = SQLCommands.returnSQLCommand(com);

        //for (String S : output){ System.out.println(S); JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter template name"); }


        //get column names
        //columnNames = new String[3];
        //columnNames[0] = "Name"; columnNames[1] = "Surname"; columnNames[2] = "Sex";

        //use column names to populate data
        //e.g. data[4][0] => "SELECT Name FROM tableName"[4]

    }

    private void displayTable(){
        //use JTable

        //new JScrollPane which uses the table

        //put JScrollpane in CENTER box

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String [] tableNames = SQLCommands.returnSQLCommand("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master");
        new ViewTable(tableNames[9]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using the SQLite CLI (command line interface) on a PC to play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

will do the trick ?

[SQL Lite PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

Answer (score 3):

> String com = "PRAGMA table_info( "+tableName+" );";

This is the correct command to execute.  According to the [SQLite docs on PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

> **PRAGMA table_info(table-name);**
>
> This pragma returns one row for each column in the named table. Columns in the result set include the column name, data type, whether or not the column can be NULL, and the default value for the column.

When I try it with SQLite via JDBC it seems to work fine:

```
JdbcDatabaseConnection compiled statement: PRAGMA table_info(foo)
[0, id, INTEGER, 0, null, 1]
[1, stuff, VARCHAR, 0, null, 0]
[2, val, INTEGER, 0, null, 0]
```

This shows that the `foo` table has 3 columns:

- 0: name 'id', type 'INTEGER', can-be-null '0' (false I guess), default-value 'null'
- 1: name 'stuff', type 'VARCHAR', can-be-null '0' (false I guess), default-value 'null'
- 2: name 'val', type 'INTEGER', can-be-null '0' (false I guess), default-value 'null'

I'm not sure what the last column is but `id` is an auto-generated field so it could be that.

Comment: I think, last column corresponds to primary key status